# Can't run the command dart while dart-sdk installed

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, command-line

I am working on a project using Flutter with Firebase. When setting up Firebase using the command:

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

The following error pops up:

```
"Error: Unable to find git in your PATH."
```

The main problem is that the dart command doesn't find git. The command dart doesn't work at all.

I installed dart-sdk using the choco command.

I uninstalled and reinstalled git.
I tried different setups of environment variables for git.

When I change the current environment variable setup of git I couldn't use the flutter command the same error pops up.

I used the command: with flutter instead of dart and **flutterfire_cli** got installed but then I can't use the command:

```
flutterfire configure
```

the same error comes out.

Guys pls some help I have been stuck in this step for 2 weeks now.

PS: I am using PowerShell from windows.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the path of your git and flutterfire files to your environmental variables.

You can read about setting env variables here.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0

This is my Path to the flutterfire file:
[image: This is my Path to the flutterfire file]

If you don't set these files to your path, powershell doesn't understand what commands you are writing, so you add them to your PATH to be able to use them in powershell.

Hope this helps

Comment: tnx for the help but it didnt work